# What gets killed with the Android UI thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In an activity, I spin off several separate threads. Later, on one of these child threads, I make the following call:

```
((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        String message = "Exception thrown: Developer mode was enabled while " +
            "trying to access the app.";
        throw new RuntimeException(message);
    }
});
```

Now, what else will be killed along with the UI thread? Will the other threads die as well? When the app crashes, it's still running in the background (I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all the threads related to that process will be killed (in a single process model scenario). You can verify it by running

```
ps -t | grep [your-app-user-id]
```

from the command line before and after the `RuntimeException`

To get the app's user id:

```
ps | grep [your-package-name]
```